# PHP regex remove non alphanumeric except period

Tags: php, regex

I'm having trouble finding a solution to this. How can I avoid losing the period in this regex?

```
$text = preg_replace('~[^\\pL\d]+~u', '-', $text);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$text = preg_replace('@[^0-9a-z\.]+@i', '-', $text);
```

This replaces anything that isn't 0-9, a-z, or a period, in a case-insenstive manner.

Comment: No need to escape the dot, although I guess it doesn't hurt.

Comment: @jeroen Today I learned! Unescaped dots make me twitchy in regexes. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just add the dot to your character class:

```
$text = preg_replace('~[^\\pL\d.]+~u', '-', $text);
```

You are using a negated character class (the `[^` part) so anything that does not match any of the characters in that character class, gets replaced.

By the way, your question title does not match your regex.

Answer (score 0):

What the heck is "\\pL"? AFAIK this matches a Backslash and the letters p and L.

Is this what you mean?

```
<?php 
echo preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9.]+/ui', '-', 'abc093.-23.-2ªıØẞÆ.23.OAIFJ→øæł¶iwoeweo');
?>
```

Result:
abc093.-23.-2-.23.OAIFJ-iwoeweo

Comment: it was from a "slugify" function for files, I obviously picked the wrong statement in the function! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't do a double escape and to be fully unicode compatible, numerics are : `\pN` then:

```
$text = preg_replace('~[^\pL\pN]+~u', '-', $text);
```